# web application threw load() exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc

Below is my dispatcher servlet. I am not using maven. Not sure of why I am facing this error. I hv include all the required jars in the build path. When I run my project facing: Web application  threw load() exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"  
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"  
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">  

<context:component-scan base-package="com.controllers"></context:component- 
scan>

<bean 
class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
<property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"></property>
 <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
 </bean>

  <bean id="ds" 
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"> 
        </property>
     <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springmvc"> 
  </property>
   <property name="username" value="root"></property>
   <property name="password" value="password"></property>
 </bean>

 <bean id="jt" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
   <property name="dataSource" ref="ds"></property>
  </bean>

 <bean id="dao" class="com.dao.EmpDao">
  <property name="template" ref="jt"></property>
 </bean>
 </beans>
```

And this is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<servlet>
<servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet- 
  class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>  
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Do you have all dependencies in you classpath?! If you build .war file are  there spring dependencies in its lib directory?

Comment: Please tell the spring version you are using. And mention the list of jars included

Comment: the error tells that you missed the Spring Web MVC jar ! `spring-webmvc`

Answer (score 2):

Its a common problem faced by many developers. Below is the simple and step by step solution to get rid of this error (Assuming eclipse based IDE)

1. Right click on the project and select Build Path > Configure Build Path.

   [image]
2. Select Deployment Assembly option from left side navigation pane, and click on Add button.

   [image]
3. Select Java Build path entries and click next.

   [image]
4. Maven dependencies option will appear if its a maven project. If its a non-maven project all the jars will be listed.  select maven dependencies/all the jars and click finish.

   [image]
5. A new entry will be created in deployment assembly list as shown. Click on apply and close button.

   [image]
6. Restart the application server and run the project again. The error will go away for sure.